# Computing the norm of the operator $T: (\Bbb R^n, \|\cdot\|_2)\to (\Bbb R^n, \|\cdot\|_1)$ with $Tx = (\delta^kx_k)_{k=1,...,n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

Let $0<\delta<1$ consider the linear operator

$$T: (\Bbb R^n, \|\cdot\|_2)\to (\Bbb R^n, \|\cdot\|_1)$$ such that for $x=(x_k)_{k=1,...,n}$ we have  $$Tx = (\delta^kx_k)_{k=1,...,n}$$

recall that $$ \|x\|_2^2=\sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|^2$$

and $$ \|x\|_1=\sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|$$

> what is the norm of the operator T.

I attempted this by using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality as follow:
Let set $\delta=(\delta^k)_{k=1,...,n}$

$$ \|Tx\|_1=\sum_{k=1}^n|\delta^kx_k|\le  \|x\|_2 \|\delta \|_2=\|x\|_2\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n\delta^{2k}}= \delta\|x\|_2\sqrt{\frac{1-\delta^{2n}}{1-\delta^{2}}}$$

Therefore, I can conclude that,

$$ \|T\|\le  \delta\sqrt{\frac{1-\delta^{2n}}{1-\delta^{2}}}$$

I don't how to go further with the  lower bound.

> Is this is inequality sharp?
>
> Does anyone has an idea how to prove wether this is inequality is sharp? namely how can find an element $x$ such that $ \|x\|_2=1$ and
> $$ \|Tx\|_1= \delta\sqrt{\frac{1-\delta^{2n}}{1-\delta^{2}}}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cauchy–Schwarz inequality is an equality when the two vectors are linearly dependent. So just try $x = (\delta, \delta^2, \dots, \delta^n)$. Let $C = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \delta^{2i}}$ be the number you found. You have:
$$\|x\|_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \delta^{2i}} = C.$$

Now $Tx = (\delta^2,\delta^4,\dots,\delta^{2k}$. Thus:
$$\|Tx\|_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n \delta^{2i} = C \|x\|_2.$$

Since you already know that $\|T\| \le C$, it follows that $\|T\| = C$.

Comment: NO comment just perfect